# Jenkins. How use one process while few stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I just want to know is it possible to change jenkins stages from other process? [image]

In this scheme all that I want. Jenkins start build and run some process (this [nuke build](https://nuke.build/) process). This process do some work and I want to change jenkins build stages synchrony with my process, is it possible? The type of process is not important in the question, consider that this is any .exe file that can be run through the command line. It is important that this is one process throughout the entire build

Comment: could you please first let us know what have you tried or show some code so the community can help you !!

Comment: @DashrathMundkar I try integrate https://nuke.build/ with Jenkins. Now it work for me as I make new nuke run in every Jenkins stages (Clean, Build and other). But I want make single nuke call in start of Jenkins build and after that update jenkins build state from nuke

Comment: @Duskone39 Jenkins Pipeline is an orchestrator of build processes. There is no way (AFAIK) you can make it mimic a build orchestrated by Nuke.